# How to add model instances to a Foreign Key field in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I need to get the `ItemModel` instances from the item model and store them in the foreign key field in the `OrderModel` but I am not sure how. I've tried to iterate through the item order list and add one but it doesn't display correctly. Any help would be much appreciated.

My goal is to display the data like this:

```
{
    "payment_method": "test", 
    "confirmation": "14087147WA285750M", 
    "total_price": "15.00", 
    "is_paid": "True", 
    "order_created": "2021-07-09T19:51:18Z", 
    "item_order": [
        {
            "id": 2, 
            "name": "Carrots", 
            "image": "image link", 
            "slug": "carrots", 
            "price": "5.00", 
            "itemID": "ct1", 
            "quantity": 1
        },
         {
            "id": 8, 
            "name": "Dog Food", 
            "image": "image link", 
            "slug": "dog-food", 
            "price": "10.00", 
            "itemID": "df4", 
            "quantity": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

View:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def create_order(request):
    user = request.user
    order = request.data

    order_item = OrderModel.objects.create(
        user=user,
        payment_method=order['payment_method'],
        confirmation=order['confirmation'],
        total_price=order['total_price'],
        is_paid=order['is_paid'],
        order_created=order['order_created'],
        item_order= """ The item model instance """
    )

    ordered_items = OrderSerializer(order_item, many=True).data

    return Response(ordered_items)
```

Order Model:

```
class OrderModel(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(CustomerModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   item_order = models.ForeignKey(
       ItemModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   payment_method = models.CharField(max_length=50)
   confirmation = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   total_price = models.DecimalField(
       max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
   is_paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   has_been_sent = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   order_created = models.DateTimeField()

   def __str__(self):
       return str(self.id)
```

Order Serializer:

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    item_order = ItemSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = OrderModel
        fields = ['payment_method', 'confirmation',
                  'total_price', 'is_paid', 'has_been_sent', 'order_created', 
                  'item_order']
        read_only_fields = ['id']
```

Comment: DRF defines how to implement writable nested serializers. Have a look here: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers

Comment: I think there is a semantic error in ForeignKey definition. Your `OrderModel` is related as many to one `ItemModel`, but in your `create_order` view you are trying to do the opposite

Comment: I tried nested serializers but I get  "OrderModel.item_order" must be an "ItemModel" instance.